# Total number of arrivals and average length of stay by hotel name and month

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to come up with an SQL Server script that shows the total number of arrivals and the average decimal length of stay by hotel name and month.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the type of output that I'm looking for:

```
HotelName          Month     TotalArrivals     AvgLengthofStay
==============================================================
Algonquin Hotel    June      300               4.25
Algonquin Hotel    July      375               3.65
The Four Seasons   June      485               4.45    
The Four Seasons   July      445               4.10
The Ritz-Carlton   June      ...               ...
```

Here's some relevant table info:

```
HOTEL:

HotelID (PK), HotelName, HotelAddress, HotelCity, HotelState, HotelPostalCode

RESERVATION:

ReservationID (PK), GuestID, RoomID (FK), CheckinDate, NumberofNights

ROOM (Only needed for table joins):

RoomID (PK), HotelID (FK)
```

EDIT:

As far as "Month" goes, I'm strictly going by the month that corresponds to the check in date, NOT the check out date.

Comment: Look into using `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions (like `COUNT` and `AVG`).

Comment: What if `CheckinDate` is 2016-05-31 and `NumberofNights` is 2?

Comment: well you cant predict it accurately because checkin date can be at the end of month and number of nights can be enough to step into next month. what would you do then?

Comment: Sorry, good point!  As far as "Month" goes, I'm strictly going by the month that corresponds to the check in date, NOT the check out date.

Comment: Give us some data, to test on. It would help alot.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE #Hotels 
( HotelID int, HotelName varchar(10), HotelAddress  varchar(10), HotelCity  varchar(10), HotelState  varchar(10), HotelPostalCode  varchar(10))

CREATE TABLE #Reservation 
(
 ReservationID int, GuestID int, RoomID int, CheckinDate datetime, NumberofNights int
)

CREATE TABLE #Room
(
 RoomID int, HotelID int

)


INSERT INTO #Hotels (HotelID,HotelName) VALUES (1,'A')
INSERT INTO #Hotels (HotelID,HotelName) VALUES (2,'B')


GO


INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (1,1,1,'2016-01-05',5)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (2,2,1,'2016-08-05',3)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (3,3,1,'2016-06-05',2)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (4,1,1,'2016-01-12',1)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (5,2,1,'2016-08-18',8)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (6,3,1,'2016-06-30',7)





INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (1,1,2,'2016-02-01',5)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (2,2,2,'2016-02-06',3)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (3,3,2,'2016-02-09',2)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (4,1,2,'2016-04-03',1)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (5,2,2,'2016-04-07',8)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (6,3,2,'2016-04-05',7)


INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (1,1,3,'2016-07-01',15)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (2,2,3,'2016-11-06',2)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (3,3,3,'2016-11-09',9)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (4,1,3,'2016-12-03',8)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (5,2,3,'2016-06-07',10)
INSERT INTO #Reservation (ReservationID,GuestID,RoomID,CheckinDate,NumberofNights) 
VALUES (6,3,3,'2016-04-05',2)



INSERT INTO #Room VALUES (1,1)
INSERT INTO #Room VALUES (2,1)
INSERT INTO #Room VALUES (3,2)
```

and the "magic" is here

```
SELECT HotelName, MONTH(re.CheckinDate) as Month, COUNT(*) as TotalArrivals, AVG(CAST(re.NumberofNights  as decimal(22,6) )) AS Avg
FROM #Hotels h 
join #Room r on r.HotelID = h.HotelID
join #Reservation re on re.RoomID = r.RoomID
GROUP BY h.HotelID, HotelName, MONTH(re.CheckinDate)
```

What you have to do is use a select, and group by HotelID and MONTH(re.CheckinDate) which will give you a month base rows ( for each hotel you will get 12 rows). Using COUNT(*) will get all the records from a month for a specific hotel, which is the total amount of arrivals and using the Avg(NumberofNights) will get you the avg number of nights.

Also i use the CASt(re.NumberofNights as decimal(22,6)) because if NumberofNights is an int ( i assume so) the avg will return also an int so for 3 arrivals and 10 night it will return 3 not 3.333333.

Hope it helps!

Comment: voted up. didnt have the time to right it down myself. good job mate

Comment: Thanks, CiucaS!  This one seems to be really close!  The only thing that isn't working correctly is the "TotalArrivals."  COUNT(*) doesn't give me the correct totals.  I'm basically looking for the total number of reservations by hotel name and month.  I tried COUNT(re.ReservationID), but that doesn't seem to work either.   Any ideas?

Comment: @amaidie90 post some sample data, so I can work with. Becouse it theory this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Please check following SQL Select statement

```
;with cte as (
select 
    h.HotelID,
    h.HotelName,
    r.ReservationID,
    DATENAME(mm,r.CheckinDate) as [month],
    r.NumberofNights * 1.0 as NumberofNights
from hotel h
inner join ROOM o on o.HotelID = h.HotelID
left join RESERVATION r on r.RoomID = o.RoomID and r.CheckinDate between '20160101' and '20161231'
)
select distinct
    HotelName,
    [month],
    COUNT(ReservationID) over (partition by HotelID, [month]) TotalArrivals,
    cast ( AVG(NumberofNights) over (partition by HotelID, [month]) as decimal(10,2))  AvgLengthofStay
from cte
```

I assume you are familiar with [SQL CTE (Common Table Expression)](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) as a T-SQL developer

In fact what is important with above Select statement is [applying OVER and PARTITION BY clause to SQL mathematical functions](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-count-function-with-partition-by-clause.aspx) like SUM(), COUNT(), AVG(), etc.

I had to multiply the length of staying days with 1.0 to get average values in decimal.
In the last step I convert the decimal to 2 points after integer part.

I hope it helps you for the solution,

Answer (score 0):

When you use an aggregate function in the select statement (SUM, AVG, COUNT, etc...) you need to make sure you group the statement by any non aggregate columns.  Each non-aggregate column selected will break your aggregated columns down into further detail.

```
SELECT HotelName,
       SUM(TotalArrivals) AS TotalArrivals,
       AVG(AvgLengthofStay) AS AvgLengthofStay
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY HotelName
```

This statement would give you the grand total of arrivals and overall average length of stay per hotel since the beginning of your table's life.

```
SELECT HotelName,
       Month,
       SUM(TotalArrivals) AS TotalArrivals,
       AVG(AvgLengthofStay) AS AvgLengthofStay
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY HotelName, Month
```

By adding the Month column, you break the aggregates down further.  Now the data will return the total arrivals and the average length of stay by hotel, broken down by month.